# defaultdict with dict as value, but value incrementation remember the previous incrementation

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict with default value as a dictionary. Let's say the the default value is something like this `{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C':0}`

And every time, I put in a new key, it's going to be something like this `{"Mary": {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C':0}}`, and if I increment one the default value by one, it should be something like this `{"Mary": {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C':0}}`.

However, here is the tricky part, if I add in a new key, it's going to be something like this, `{"Mary": {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C':0}, "Tom":{'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C':0}}`, and I wonder why? Shouldn't Tom be `{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C':0}`?

Can someone explain this to me why this is happening and how do I make sure every time I put in a new key, the initialization is going to be actually the original initialization not the newly incremented initialization? And also if I increment different letter with the same key already in the dictionary, it's going to increment as usual?

And by the way, I am doing this in a class, you guys can follow the template below:

```
class Tokenization: 
    def __init__(self): 
        # Let's assume I created the defaultdict here in the __init__ function

    def add_one_key(self, names, letter): 
        for name in names: 
           defaultdict[name][letter] += 1
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C':0}` as default value because it creates one dictionary in memory and later it use reference to this object - and all `names` use the same dictionary in memory. Better use normal dictionary and before you add element you could check `if name not in defaultdict: defaultdict[name] = {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C':0}`

Comment: how did you create this dictionary ? I can't reproduce this problem. You runs `defaultdict[name][letter] += 1` for all names so all names should have the same values

Comment: It's Ok, your first comment already solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as the `default_factory` parameter:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(lambda: {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C':0})

dct["Mary"]['A'] = 1
print(dct["Mary"]) # {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
print(dct["Tom"])  # {'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0}
```

Actually when we do something like `defaultdict(int)`, we are in fact passing function `int` to `defaultdict`. Then `int()` (which always returns `0`) is called whenever a default value is needed.